# Dynamically turning on NSLogs

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor, nslog

I am currently using the following DebugLog macro

```
#if defined(DEBUG) && defined(useDebugLogs)
#define DebugLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%s:(%d)> %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#else
#define DebugLog( s, ... ) 
#endif
```

However, now with test flight allowing remote logging this is a little dated.

Basically what I want to do is add a switch in my settings.plist to allow the user to turn on remote logging.

I've come across this tutorial
http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-do-dynamic-debug-logging-in.html

However, it's a very poor explanation and doesn't actually seem to work.

Comment: Did you ever try out [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger)?

Comment: DEBUG is only defined during... (surprise) debugging.  In release code, this won't work.

Comment: @AndyFriese I haven't used it however, I saw it in the comments of that tutorial but it appears to be almost too much. I just want a simple switch

Comment: why not just enable them and control what messages you receive by improving your implementation, posting updates, improving your implementation, posting updates, improving your implementation, posting updates, improving your implementation, posting updates, improving your implementation, posting updates…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, the best way IMO is to just always send the logs and tweak your implementation so you see exactly what you want. you either want analytics, or you won't use them. there is an error, or there is not. work your way through them and improve your signal to noise ratio. anyways…

you could just create a dedicated function for this purpose. it can conditionally log or not based on some variable in your implementation. note that you may forward your va_list by calling `NSLogv` rather than `NSLog`, or you may use `-[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]` to forward the message + arguments elsewhere:

**MONDebugLog.h**

```
extern void MONDebugLog(NSString * format, ... ) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

**MONDebugLog.m**

```
void MONDebugLog(NSString * format, ... ) {

    enum {
        MONLog_Undefined,
        MONLog_Enable,
        MONLog_Disable
    };

    static int DoLog = MONLog_Undefined;
    if (MONLog_Undefined == DoLog) {
        DoLog = ...load from plist or defaults and set to Log_Enable or Log_Disable...;
    }

    if (MONLog_Disable == DoLog) {
        return;
    }
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, format);
    NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arguments];
    va_end(arguments);
    ...now log or xmit str...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is just turning on or off logging there's an easy, yet powerful solution. The idea is to redirect stderr to /dev/null:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void setLoggingEnabled(BOOL enabled)
{
    static int copyOfStdErr = -1;
    if (enabled) {
        if (copyOfStdErr == -1)
            return;
        dup2(copyOfStdErr, STDERR_FILENO);
        close(copyOfStdErr);
        copyOfStdErr = -1;
    } else {
        if (copyOfStdErr != -1)
            return;
        copyOfStdErr = dup(STDERR_FILENO);
        int fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
        dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO);
        close(fd);
    }
}
```

This solution has some advantages:

- You don't have to use your own logging mechanism in your code, it just works with `NSLog`
- There's no preprocessor magic involved.
- It also works for third party libraries that emit output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
#define boolDebug_IsActivated       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"UseDebug"]

#define DebugLog( s, ... ) \
if (boolDebug_IsActivated) {\
    NSLog( @"<%s:(%d)> %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] );\
} \
else {\
}
```

When you want to activate/deactivate, just change the object value "UseDebug" in the `NSUserDefaults`.

Example :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"UseDebug"];
DebugLog(@"comment that should not appear");
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"UseDebug"];
DebugLog(@"comment that should appear");
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution. But would it be checking the UserDefaults every time? It seems like that would be pretty slow.